# What is the difference between a US Part 121 Supplemental Air Carrier, and a US Part 135 Air Carrier?

Tags: far-135, far-121

I am a little confused after knowing the concept of Part 121 Supplemental Air Carriers in the US. What is the difference with Part 135 Air Carriers? My understanding is that both operate in a non-scheduled basis.

Comment: I don't know anything about part 121 supplemental carriers, but part 135 can operate scheduled or unscheduled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/what-are-airline-flag-and-supplemental-operations#:~:text=Supplemental%20Operations%20are%20usually%20a,passenger%20charter%20of%20an%20airliner.